# I need to save 500 word sentence in mysql database

Tags: mysql

I need to save 500 word sentence in MySQL database. What is data type should I use? I used varchar. ( It worked with xampp)

But when creating table on real server......

> Error :#1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 1000
>   bytes

Comment: it looks like you're trying to build an index over that column. The error message says you can't.

Answer (score 1):

You could use data type TEXT.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

You also need to remove the key from the column in question since you cannot have a key on it.

Comment: Even text use, following error came :-(

#1170 - BLOB/TEXT column 'quote' used in key specification without a key length

Comment: You have a key defined on that column. You cannot have one. If you need a key then you must use another column. @Raplus